# Moving sharepoint web services to new server and connect to existing SQL with existing Sharepoint databases

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration

I have SharePoint Services 2.0 installed on Server1 and the config and content databases on SQL 2000 on Server2. Server 1 is failing so I want to install SharePoint Services on new server and connect to the databases on server2 so that I can decommission Server1. Could someone give me the steps to accomplish this?

Note
The new server will also be windows 2003 with the same version of sharepoint services -  used for intranet only - small network so I can manually re point each workstation to new server

Thanks

Blair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this scenario, I would perform the following steps.

1. Install SharePoint on your new server.
2. Add your new server to the existing SharePoint farm.
3. Verify your new server is fully functional.
4. Remove your old server from the SharePoint farm.

Hope this helps!

Install: http://sharepointdotnetwiki.iblogger.org/2010/06/installing-wss3/?i=1
Remove Server From Farm: http://www.bedford.k12.pa.us/_vti_bin/help/1033/sps/html/RemovingAServerFromTheServerFarm.htm

Comment: You're quite welcome! If this answers your question, please mark as the answer.